# permutations of two lists in python

Tags: python

I have two lists like:

```
list1 = ['square','circle','triangle']
list2 = ['red','green']
```

How can I create all permutations of these lists, like this:

```
[
  'squarered', 'squaregreen',
  'redsquare', 'greensquare',
  'circlered', 'circlegreen',
  'redcircle', 'greencircle',
  'trianglered', 'trianglegreen',
  'redtriangle', 'greentriangle'
]
```

Can I use `itertools` for this?

Comment: A lot of people seem to be missing the requirement for permutations in both orders. (E.g., 'squarered' and 'redsquare'.) Maybe you should make this more explicit.

Comment: Wow, definitely missed that part. Updated my solution to fix this.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> map(''.join, itertools.chain(itertools.product(list1, list2), itertools.product(list2, list1)))
['squarered', 'squaregreen', 'circlered',
'circlegreen', 'trianglered', 'trianglegreen',
'redsquare', 'redcircle', 'redtriangle', 'greensquare',
'greencircle', 'greentriangle']
```

Answer (score 113):

You want the **[`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)** method, which will give you the **[Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)** of both lists.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> b = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']

>>> for r in itertools.product(a, b): print r[0] + r[1]
foox
fooy
fooz
foow
barx
bary
barz
barw
bazx
bazy
bazz
bazw
```

Your example asks for the bidirectional product (that is, you want 'xfoo' as well as 'foox'). To get that, just do another product and chain the results:

```
>>> for r in itertools.chain(itertools.product(a, b), itertools.product(b, a)):
...   print r[0] + r[1]
```

Comment: The OP wants the product in both orders, this solution is not complete.

Comment: Fixed now; didn't catch that as a requirement.

Comment: This solution is superior to the one marked correct do not know why op didn't mark this one

Answer (score 18):

How about

```
[x + y for x in list1 for y in list2] + [y + x for x in list1 for y in list2]
```

Example IPython interaction:

```
In [3]: list1 = ['square', 'circle', 'triangle']

In [4]: list2 = ['red', 'green']

In [5]: [x + y for x in list1 for y in list2] + [y + x for x in list1 for y in list2]
Out[5]: 
['squarered',
 'squaregreen',
 'circlered',
 'circlegreen',
 'trianglered',
 'trianglegreen',
 'redsquare',
 'greensquare',
 'redcircle',
 'greencircle',
 'redtriangle',
 'greentriangle']
```

Answer (score 12):

I think what you are looking for is the product of two lists, not the permutations:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import itertools
list1=['square','circle','triangle'] 
list2=['red','green']
for shape,color in itertools.product(list1,list2):
    print(shape+color)
```

yields

```
squarered
squaregreen
circlered
circlegreen
trianglered
trianglegreen
```

If you'd like both `squarered` and `redsquare`, then you could do something like this:

```
for pair in itertools.product(list1,list2):
    for a,b in itertools.permutations(pair,2):
        print(a+b)
```

or, to make it into a list:

```
l=[a+b for pair in itertools.product(list1,list2)
   for a,b in itertools.permutations(pair,2)]
print(l)
```

yields

```
['squarered', 'redsquare', 'squaregreen', 'greensquare', 'circlered', 'redcircle', 'circlegreen', 'greencircle', 'trianglered', 'redtriangle', 'trianglegreen', 'greentriangle']
```

Answer (score 8):

You can in any case do something like:

```
perms = []
for shape in list1:
  for color in list2:
    perms.append(shape+color)
```

Comment: its big brain time, totally forgot about this

Answer (score -1):

Simple list comprehension will give the result

```
from itertools import product
final_list = [a + b for a, b in product(list1, list2)]
```

Comment: Incorrect, you will just have half of the result with this. A correct answer with list comprehension has already been given https://stackoverflow.com/a/1953216/10326291