# Permutation List with Variable Dependencies- UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, function, error-handling, permutation

I was trying to break down the code to the simplest form before adding more variables and such. I'm stuck.

I wanted it so when I use `intertools` the first response is the permutations of `tricks` and the second response is dependent on the trick's  `landings()` and is a permutation of the trick's corresponding landing. I want to add additional variables that further branch off from `landings()` and so on.

The simplest form should print a list that looks like:

```
Backflip Complete
Backflip Hyper
180 Round Complete
180 Round Mega
Gumbi Complete
```

My Code:

```
from re import I
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools
from io import StringIO


backflip = "Backflip"
one80round = "180 Round"
gumbi = "Gumbi"
tricks = [backflip,one80round,gumbi]

complete = "Complete"
hyper = "Hyper"
mega = "Mega"

backflip_landing = [complete,hyper]
one80round_landing = [complete,mega]
gumbi_landing = [complete]

def landings(tricks):
    if tricks == backflip:
        landing = backflip_landing
    elif tricks == one80round:
        landing = one80round_landing
    elif tricks == gumbi:
        landing = gumbi_landing
    return landing

for trik, land in itertools.product(tricks,landings(tricks)):
    trick_and_landing = (trik, land)
    result = (' '.join(trick_and_landing))
    tal = StringIO(result)
    tl = (pd.DataFrame((tal)))
    print(tl)
```

I get the error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'landing' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `landing = ""` after `def landings(tricks):` to get rid of the error.

But the if checks in your function are wrong. You check if `tricks`, which is a list, is equal to `backflip`, etc. which are all strings. So thats why none of the ifs are true and `landing` got no value assigned.

[That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953194/permutations-of-two-lists-in-python) question was also about permutation in python. Maybe it helps.