# Python: What is the most efficient way to create list of lists that each item is unique depending on another nested list?

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have REST API that receive arbitrary data which I sort and convert it into list of lists, e.g.

```py
attributes = [ ['nike', 'adidas', 'salmon'], ['38'], ['blue', 'grey'] ]
```

What I want is to create new list of lists that each element in sub-lists mapped uniquely with others, like:

```py
paths = [ ['nike', '38', 'blue'], 
          ['nike', '38', 'grey'],
          ['adidas', '38', 'blue'], 
          ['adidas', '38', 'grey'],
          ['salmon', '38', 'blue'], 
          ['salmon', '38', 'grey'] ]
```

I appreciate your answers and suggestions to achieve that in most possible efficient way.

Comment: You are looking for Cartesian product. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/how-to-get-the-cartesian-product-of-multiple-lists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [permutations of two lists in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953194/permutations-of-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: @montardon Thanx for your response, it's the right solution.

Comment: @match Thanx for your suggestion, but it's look like **`itertools.product`** the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As comments suggest, you can use [product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) function from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) lib.

```py
>>> from itertools import product
>>> attributes = [ ['nike', 'adidas', 'salmon'], ['38'], ['blue', 'grey'] ]
>>> product(*attributes)
<itertools.product object at 0x7fba3ca3a080>
>>> set(product(*attributes))
{('adidas', '38', 'grey'), ('salmon', '38', 'grey'), ('nike', '38', 'blue'), ('adidas', '38', 'blue'), ('salmon', '38', 'blue'), ('nike', '38', 'grey')}
```

Comment: Appreciate your response and suggestion that saved my day, it's the right answer.